# Which method I should rewrite or write a new method?

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, cart, sales

**Normal Proc:**

We configure the **UPS/FedEx... etc** credentials and other `api` details in `Magento Admin` Panel.

In cart/checkout page, Magento shows the shipping rates based on configured account details.

If I want to change/show the third party account rates, I will show the custom fields in cart/checkout page based on these credentials, as well as the shipping rates.

If a customer enters values for those custom fields, how can I pass those credentials and get the associated shipping rates.

**I mean, which method I should rewrite? Or should I write a new method?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you mean you want to over ride the calculations of UPS/FEDEX?

Comment: @user6451, No, Actually shipping rates are based on account number? right. So I just know where magento get the credentials from config for getting shipping rates.

Comment: @user6451, from `requestShippingRates()` method also just passing country,item details there is no credentials/account details are getting to get the shipping rates.

Comment: This link may help you
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shipping/how_to_setup_ups_shipping_for_default_and_negotiated_rates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but i think you want to know the database table where ups details are stored:

In the table `sales_flat_shipment_track`
`order_id` :  this is a key value which matches `order_id` in `sales_flat_shipment_grid` and `parent_id` in `sales_flat_order_address` and `entity_id` in `sales_flat_order`
number : `UPS tracking number`